# My webrole.cs can't seem to find a connection string

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, azure

I've got a Azure/Cloud based project (single project only). It has a WCF/WebRole added to the project. My WCF services are using the entity framework to talk to a SQLAzure database. This is working very well.

In the web.config of the project I have the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CommuteEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Db.CommuteDataModel.csdl|res://*/Db.CommuteDataModel.ssdl|res://*/Db.CommuteDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=<db-here>.database.windows.net;initial catalog=dandr;persist security info=True;user id=<user-id-here>;password=<password-here>;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot; " providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

All's well so far. So I want to do a small amount of scheduled background processing (based on a timer and not an incoming request). Its too small a task to justify starting a WorkerRole for the job.

So instead, I created something like the following in the WebRole projects `WebRole.cs`

```
public override void Run()
{
    while (true)
    {
      //This is for debug purposes:
      string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CommuteEntities"].ToString();

      BackgroundProcessing.BackgroundProcessing.BackgroundProcess();
      Thread.Sleep(150000); //2.5mins
    }
}
```

For some reason the line to get the connection string just does not seem to work. However, putting the same code into a WCF service works just great.

Just to emphasis, there is only one project in this solution and the `WebRole.cs` is located in the same project as the working WCF services.

**Note**: The getting of the connection string is just for debug purposes. The underlying issue that I have is that when my WebRole.cs tries to access a Entity it gets the following exception message:

`The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.`

**Note 2:**: I've just noticed that it would appear that anything in my `WebRole.cs` can't see anything that has been configured in the `Web.config` file. Is there something that I'm not doing correctly or misunderstanding?

Anybody come across this before or have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I fell foul of the following: [Azure web role process not loading web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267130/azure-web-role-process-not-loading-web-config)

From that answer:

@stevemarx from personal communication - "Code in webrole.cs is running in a different process from the web application under IIS, and while you should certainly be able to open up web.config and read it (it’s just a file in the current directory), .NET won’t do anything special with web.config there. (It would be like putting a file called web.config in the same directory as a console app you were running.)"

So no, code in the webrole.cs process will not load my web.config.

Some more info here:

http://laorient.blogspot.com/2011/06/windows-azure-webrolecs-is-not-running.html

Comment: I'm with Damien on this one. I'd also go so far as saying you really should put something like this into your cloud service configuration. This move will also allow you to rotate the credentials without having to redeploy your application.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and stupid solution is adding an `app.config` and putting in there the configurations you need. Then load the configuration from inside the `Run()` method (db connection strings, etc.). It works!

The rest of the stuff (services, etc.) is hosted in IIS and you can easily load `web.config` file's configurations there.